# Can't find user by name with Monk / Mongo

Tags: mongodb, monk

I'm working on a CRUD application with Node, Mongo & Monk.
I'd like to find a record by username, and then update it.
But I'm unable to find a record, this code isn't working:

```
// GET User Profile
router.get('/userprofile', function(request,response){
  var db = request.db;
  var userName = request.body.username;
  var collection = db.get('usercollection');
  collection.findOne({
  "username": userName
   },{},function(e,user){
   response.render('userprofile', {
     "user": user
     });
   });
  });
```

The "findOne" method doesn't return anything, and the "user" object ends up empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the middle empty object from the signature for the **[`findOne()`](https://github.com/Automattic/monk#signatures)** method signature for the query to work:

**Note**: The way you are getting the `userName` is for when the request method is a POST, here you are doing a GET so you need to use the `request.query` property. More details [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)

```
var userName = request.query.username;
collection.findOne({"username": userName}, function(e,user){
    response.render('userprofile', { "user": user });
});
```

---

If you want to update then you can use the **[`update()`](https://github.com/Automattic/monk#updating)** method, suppose you want to update the `username` field to change it to `'foo'`, the following stub shows how you can do the update:

```
var u = collection.update({ "username": userName }, { "$set": { username: 'foo' } });
u.complete(function (err, result) {
    console.log(err); // should be null
    console.log(result); // logs the write result
});
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.  I went back and used an response(send) and it turns out my username is blank:  `response.send(request.body.username + " is the search key");` returns an undefined response, even though the URL looks like a proper query: `http://localhost:3000/userprofile?username=fred`.   The original form I used to get the route is this:  ` `form#formEditUser(name="edituser",method="get",action="/userprofile")
        input#inputUserName(type="hidden",value=user.username,name="username")
        button#btnSubmit(type="submit") Edit`

Comment: The way you are getting the `userName` is for when the request method is a POST, here you are doing a GET so you need to use the `request.query` property. More details [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out the problem.
Chridam's code was correct, but I also needed to change my form from a GET to a POST.  Once I did that, the form POSTed and mongo could see `request.body.username` (it was null before) and look up my user using Chridam's code.

After reading Chridam's revised answer, was also able to get it to work with GET.

Now working on the update code..